# LazyLoadImages and Beautifulsoup web scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lazy-loading

I'm trying to get all "img" tags from a website (including "alt" and "src"). Everything is fine, but I'm having problems with some images loaded using `lazyload` (beautifulsoup can't find any tag but those tags exists in my browser).

I'm using this, but of course, this is not working...

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
images = soup.find_all('img')

for image in images:
    name=image('alt')
    link=image('src')
    print(name, link)
```

How could I do it in a website with `lazyloadimage`?

Answer (score 0):

```py
goal = [(x.get('alt','N/A'), x.get('src', 'N/A') for x in soup.select('img')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I'm sorry. Maybe I was not so clear. My question is "how to get those images loaded using lazyloadimage"? They appears in my browser (the tag "img" exist when I use DevTools of Chrome and the website is loaded), but I can't access to them with beautifulsoup because, when I execute print(image), "img" tag is empty. It doesn't exist

Comment: @Crist023 in that case, use `selenium` since `requests` will not be able to render `LazyLoadImages`!

Comment: Ok, thank you!! I will do it with Selenium